# ReferenceError: <function> is not defined at HTMLElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to allow a user to input multiple tags and be able to remove them from the array by use of a text box, an example would be how stackoverflow lets you add tags when asking a question, i have been able to add the values to the array, however i get an error when i run the remove function. this is the javascript i have written below:

```
  <script type="module">
import {getDatabase, ref, set, child, get} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-database.js";
const db = getDatabase();

const ul = document.querySelector(".statementbox");
const input = ul.querySelector('.inputstate');

let tags = [];

function createTag(){
  //removing li tas before adding so there will be no duplication
  ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.remove());
  tags.slice().reverse().forEach(tag =>{
    let liTag = `<li>${tag} <i class="fas fa-times" onclick="remove(this,'${tag}')"></i> </li>`;
    ul.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag); //adding li inside ul tag
  });
}

function remove(element, tag){
  let index = tags.indexOf(tag); // getting removing tag index
  tags = [...tags.slice(0, index), ...tags.slice(index + 1)]; // removing the tag from the array
  console.log(tags);
}

function addTag(e){
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    let tag = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); //removing unwanted spaces from tag
    if (tag.length > 1 && !tags.includes(tag)) { //if tag length is greater than one and does not already exist
      tag.split(',').forEach(tag => {//splitting each tag from comma
        tags.push(tag); //adding tag to the array
        createTag();
      });
    }
    e.target.value = "";
  }
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", addTag);

</script>
```

I don't understand the cause of the error because i have done the research and the function is not inside another function nor is it linked to a script with src nor is it wrapped within another function, i tried adding the `remove()` in a separate script and it did log it in the console, however when i do this my array comes up blank.

Please advise on what to do, thanks in advance.

Comment: The function is in _module scope_ which is inaccessible outside the module. `onclick` is executed as a separate script. Why would you use `onclick` anyway?

Comment: what would be a better approach to use?

Comment: Onclick seemed easier to use in making it refer to `this`

Comment: I’d do ``.forEach((tag) => ul.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", document.createElement("li")).append(`${tag} `, Object.assign(document.createElement("i"), { className: "fas fa-times remove-icon" })))``, and then use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation), i.e. at the bottom of the module put: `ul.addEventListener("click", ({`[`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target)`}) => { const rmIcon = target.closest(".remove-icon"); if(rmIcon){ remove(rmIcon, rmIcon.previousSibling.textContent.slice(0, -1)); } });`.

Comment: Also, put `element.closest("li").remove();` inside the `remove` function (seems to be missing).

Comment: I actually have not understood your approach, could you help explain it better?

Comment: See [`insertAdjacentElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement), [`createElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/append), [`Object.assign`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [`closest`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), [`previousSibling`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling), [`textContent`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).